# playing multiple jwplayer videos

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to create a video triptych kind of thing.

I was wondering if there was a way I could create a play button that starts all three videos at once.

The best solution I've managed was having three autoplay and have a refresh button added to restart the process.

My boss provided me with a link to a colleague of his who had done this with javascript, but for three separate youtube videos. I'm using JWplayer and I was really just wondering if anyone could send me in the right direction.

Here is what I have for one of the jwplayer sections,

```
<!-- Fat Man -->
    <!-- World Wide Walks: -->
            <!-- Container -->
            <div id="centering_container_c" class="margin_top_pic_pages">
                    <div id="container_video_c">Loading the player ...
                    </div>
                    <!-- video -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("container_video_c").setup({
                    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
                    file: "videos/DESERTS/4NMFATMANsmall.mp4",
                    image: "WorldWideWalks/images/NewMexico/4NMFATMAN.JPG",
                    height: 135, /*previously 324*/
                    width: 240, /*previously 576*/
                    controlbar: "none",
                    autostart: "false",
                    screencolor: "#ffffff",
                    backcolor: "#ffffff",
                    wmode: "transparent",
                    events: {
                        }
                    });
            </script>


</div><!--end video -->
  <!-- End Fat Man -->
```

Comment: We can't send you in the right direction if we don't know where you currently are.  Show us the HTML and Javascript that you've got so far.

Comment: Alright yeah I was a tad nervous about posting stuff because my boss is an artist who is very particular about showing his work. Hes encouraged me to reach out about this tho. edit: I've added one of the players as a snippet, I haven't made any changes to JWplayers JS file. I'm guessing theres something I can add to the events to make a link that plays all three videos.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve. If it is to have a set of videos added as a playlist you can do this. You'll have to adapt it a bit as I use it to play music files. Basically, I generate the playlist of files via php for a joomla site.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
                playerInstance.setup({
                playlist: [{
//DYNAMICALLY GENERATED PLAYLIST
                    <?php
                        $album_id = $this->item->album_id;
                        // Get default database object
                        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                        // Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
                        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
                        $query = 'SELECT name, filename, position FROM #__songs WHERE `album_id` = ' . $db->quote( (int) $album_id ) . ' ORDER BY `num` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30';
                        $db->setQuery($query);
                        $results = $db -> loadAssocList();
                        foreach($results as $row){
                        echo "file: \"../songs/". htmlentities($row['file_name']). "\", ";
                        echo "title: \"". htmlentities($row['title']). "\"";
                        echo "},{";
                        }
                    ?>
//END DYNAMICALLY GENERATED PLAYLIST
                }],
                skin:       '../jwplayer/jwplayer-7.1.4/skins/five.css',
                autostart:  'false',
                repeat:     'true',
                startparam: 'starttime',
                stretching: 'fill',

                width:      '100%',
                height:     '30'
                });
        </script>
```

This loads a playlist of songs from the database and plays them in album order. I I wanted to play videos I would make the player height larger and point to the videos in the database.